# How to mock query for joined tables in SQLAlchemy and alchemy-mock when where-statement filters data from multiple tables?

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, python-mock

I have schema:

```
CREATE SCHEMA problem AUTHORIZATION blockchain;

CREATE TABLE problem.users (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    nick varchar NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE problem.passwords_keys (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    user_id serial references problem.users,
    password varchar NOT NULL,
    valid bool NOT null DEFAULT TRUE
);
```

For the schema I've generated SLQAlchemy classes with [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/):

```
export DB_PASSWORD=...
export DB_USER=...
sqlacodegen "postgresql://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@localhost/default_database --schema problem | tee schema.py
# coding: utf-8
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, text
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'problem'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('problem.users_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    nick = Column(String, nullable=False)


class PasswordsKey(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'passwords_keys'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'problem'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('problem.passwords_keys_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    user_id = Column(ForeignKey('problem.users.id'), nullable=False, server_default=text("nextval('problem.passwords_keys_user_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    valid = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, server_default=text("true"))

    user = relationship('User')
```

Those classes I want to mock to perform query:

```
SELECT p."password" "password" FROM 
    problem.passwords_keys p 
    JOIN problem.users u ON(p.user_id=u.id) 
    WHERE p."valid" = true AND u.nick = 'Bush';
```

So I've created code:

```
from mock_alchemy.mocking import UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock  # pip3 install mock-alchemy
from unittest import mock
import schema

nick = 'Bush'

session = UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock(data=[
    (
        [
            mock.call.query(schema.PasswordsKey),
            mock.call.join(schema.User),
            mock.call.filter(schema.PasswordsKey.valid == True),
            mock.call.filter(schema.User.nick == nick),
        ],
        [schema.PasswordsKey(id=2, user_id=22, password='qwerty1', valid=True)]
    ),
])

keys_for_user = session.query(schema.PasswordsKey)\
    .join(schema.User)\
    .filter(schema.PasswordsKey == True)\
    .filter(schema.User.nick == nick)
password = keys_for_user.first().password
print(f'1. Found private key {password} by nick "{nick}"')
```

But it is not working:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/agh/Pulpit/blockchain/watra-ledger/src/stack/mock.py", line 32, in <module>
    password = keys_for_user.first().password
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'password'
```

---

What is interesting that when I do not filter with another table - everything is working:

```
from mock_alchemy.mocking import UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock  # pip3 install mock-alchemy
from unittest import mock
import schema

session = UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock(data=[
    (
        [
            mock.call.query(schema.PasswordsKey),
            mock.call.join(schema.User),
            mock.call.filter(schema.PasswordsKey.valid == True),
         ],
        [schema.PasswordsKey(id=1, user_id=11, password='qwerty', valid=True)]
    ),
])

keys_for_user = session.query(schema.PasswordsKey)\
    .join(schema.User)\
    .filter(schema.PasswordsKey.valid == True)
row = keys_for_user.first()
print(f'2. Found valid password "{row.password}"')
```

And the result is:

```
2. Found valid password "qwerty"
```

---

Another solution which I found is not to mock filtering, but it looks dirty for me (IMO the code is to just make tests pass not to test):

```
from mock_alchemy.mocking import UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock  # pip3 install mock-alchemy
from unittest import mock
import schema

nick = 'Bush'

session = UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock(data=[
    (
        [
            mock.call.query(schema.PasswordsKey),
            mock.call.join(schema.User),
            # mock.call.filter(schema.PasswordsKey.valid == True),
            # mock.call.filter(schema.User.nick == nick),
         ],
        [schema.PasswordsKey(id=1, user_id=11, password='qwerty', valid=True)]
    ),
])

keys_for_user = session.query(schema.PasswordsKey)\
    .join(schema.User)\
    .filter(schema.PasswordsKey == True)\
    .filter(schema.User.nick == nick)
password = keys_for_user.first().password
print(f'3. Found private key {password} by nick "{nick}"')
```

---

**Unfortunately I need to filter by user nick and there must be some way to make this working.**

Comment: Could you please share the exact python code you want to mock?

Comment: The code is shared. It is 4th code in the question

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found out - there is no problem with querying joined tables - it is problem that `mock.call.filter` should be called once even for multiple filters.

So instead of:

```
session = UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock(data=[
    (
        [
            mock.call.query(schema.PasswordsKey),
            mock.call.join(schema.User),
            # mock.call.filter(schema.PasswordsKey.valid == True),
            # mock.call.filter(schema.User.nick == nick),
         ],
        [schema.PasswordsKey(id=1, user_id=11, password='qwerty', valid=True)]
    ),
])
```

We should do:

```
session = UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock(data=[
    (
        [
            mock.call.query(schema.PasswordsKey),
            mock.call.join(schema.User),
            mock.call.filter(schema.PasswordsKey.valid == True, 
                             schema.User.nick == nick),
         ],
        [schema.PasswordsKey(id=1, user_id=11, password='qwerty', valid=True)]
    ),
])
```

---

[Link](https://mock-alchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/index.html?highlight=filter#dynamic-session-limitation) to example in official documentation.